# Drivers of RTL8111/8168 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller for ESXi 6.0

Tags: vmware-esxi

I have installed ESXi 6.0 on a server which has a Realtek  RTL8111/8168 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller.

It's not displayed in the Network Adapters list due to ESXi 6.0 not having RTL8111/8168 PCI Express Gigabit drivers.

What's the solution for this?

Comment: Use supported hardware, and please re-read our help on what this site is and isn't for - we're here for professional sysadmins, not people just messing about with consumer gear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realtek cards aren't a good hardware option for things like ESXi. Although it will work adding the required drivers for the card, this isn't recommended and not supported by VMware.

Those Realtek NICs are just to bad for ESXi environment.

Anyway, you can follow this guide to use the card:
https://tinkertry.com/install-esxi-5-5-with-realtek-8111-or-8168-nic

It's for ESXi 5.5 but it should work in 6.0. And even in the guide, it's says to get something better.

I do recommends cards from Intel, because they are good, supported and relatively cheap.

EDIT: Here's a more updated guide for ESXi 6.0
http://www.vdicloud.nl/2015/02/07/realtek-nic-on-vsphere-6/

Answer (score 0):

If, and only if, your hardware is supported, you install drivers from .zip packages imported into Update Manager.

Save the package somewhere accessible by your vCenter gui. Update Manager -> Patch Repository -> Import Patches.  Use the wizard to add the zip package.

Probably want to add it to a new baseline, dynamic.

Back in Update Manager, add your baseline and remediate that sucker!